# setSupportActionBar in AppCompactActivity cannot be applied android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I cannot add action bar in my app it keeps on giving an error, moreover, when I add the toolbar it does not show anything in the layout

here is the screenshot of the code::

[image]

The full code is following...>>>>

```
package com.example.prateek.holachat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.view.Menu;    
import android.widget.Toolbar;    
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;   
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Toolbar mtoolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mtoolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBarNew);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HOLA !");


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {

            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            finish();

        }


    }


     }
```

And here is the screenshot of toolBar XML file..>>>

[image]

Comment: replace `import android.widget.Toolbar` with `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, in order not to provoke a cast exception.

Comment: We've been discussing this issue years ago i guess. Of course it's because of Casting to `Toolbar` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: Thanks.. that worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the v7 libraries are used to support devices with old android versions. If you want to provide a the support use  `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` with `setSupportActionBar()`

Otherwise as in your case you have `import android.widget.Toolbar;` so use `setActionBar()` instead.